# No such module while importing my custom framework to the project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, import, ios-frameworks

I followed [this tutorial](http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/) and also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uZ5lUkEzlGM) to create my custom framework. Once I build it for the simulator version/or both simulator and device, I would like to add this to my project. I just drag and drop it to project:

My **PersonFramework** within project navigator:

[image]

Target membership for my **PersonFramework**:

[image]

**Linked Frameworks** for my App target.

[image]

And finally my try to import this to the project:

[image]

> No such module `PersonFramework`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you solved it? I meet  the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

`FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting needs to point to the location of the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Close the Xcode.

Go into user(you)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and delete the folder contents.

If you have a build of you app in a running simulator you'll need to also delete the build folders.

Reopen the Xcode. Clean & Build.